# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Tridion Stack Exchange](http://tridion.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How should I detect whether any of a list of links resolves?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2983/how-should-i-detect-whether-any-of-a-list-of-links-resolves)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [When uploading an image (jpeg, gif file etc) using WebDAV can I select which multimedia schema is used?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/when-uploading-an-image-jpeg-gif-file-etc-using-webdav-can-i-select-which-mul)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are possible ways to insert super-scripted symbols in non-RTF fields](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2891/what-are-possible-ways-to-insert-super-scripted-symbols-in-non-rtf-fields)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [DD4T RTF images pre-pended with incorrect path](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/dd4t-rtf-images-pre-pended-with-incorrect-path)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Issue installing the Content Porter client](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/issue-installing-the-content-porter-client)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Fetching information from a page template in a component template Tridion 2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/fetching-information-from-a-page-template-in-a-component-template-tridion-2011)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Tridion UI - ExperienceManager Startup](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3065/tridion-ui-experiencemanager-startup)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Error importing using Content Porter 2009 SP1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/error-importing-using-content-porter-2009-sp1)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Update content in a file being published using storage extension](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3045/update-content-in-a-file-being-published-using-storage-extension)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Unable to map all paths to URIs in GetDefaultData Core Service call](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/unable-to-map-all-paths-to-uris-in-getdefaultdata-core-service-call)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we're mainly competing with StackExchange for similar types of questions and content.

Some of our questions might seem basic but don't necessarily have a public equivalent out there. We still encourage askers to provide research and share what they've tried.

I'm biased in that I'd prefer to see more functional questions, but these don't necessarily have clear cut, well-scoped answers and can get into "it depends" type discussions and comes down to preference and design choices.

Btw, it's hard to discuss [the list](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval/history) without seeing the questions and how they fared. I felt some of my answers were arbitrary--if I took the survey again, I might vote differently.